# Constantly popping up errors

Tags: grails

I am constantly getting these errors in the error log-:

> Error in JDT during AST creation. Problems occured when invoking code
>   from plugin :"org.eclipse.jdt.ui".

From time to time there is a pop up telling that-:

> An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip".
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.plus(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava/util/List;